# Mocha Loading Blank in Browser

Tags: javascript, html, bdd, mocha.js, chai

### Context

I've used Mocha before many times, both in the browser and just using the command line. I tend to use Chai's expect module for bdd.

I have five test files that have been working with command line `npm test`. I just want to run the tests in the browser for better debugging.

### Problem

The setup is just boggling my mind. I either get a blank Mocha page without tests or I see the first test flash on screen, then it redirects.

### Current specRunner.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML
<html>
<head>
  <title>Mocha Tests</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/mocha/mocha.css" />
  <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/chai/chai.js"></script>
  <script>mocha.setup('bdd');</script>
  <script src="mineLocation.js"></script>
  <script src="test/mineTests.js"></script>
  <script>
      window.expect = chai.expect;
      mocha.run();
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mocha"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Previous Attempts

- I've tried moving script tags around, thinking that dependencies are being unmet at load time.
- I've tried relative vs. absolute paths. Console says all the tags are loading correctly.
- I've tried modifying the run script tag. When it is as the example above, it turns out a blank page and says "Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null", pointing back to Mocha:

[image]

- When the run script tag looks like this:

  ```
  $(function() {
      window.mochaPhantomJS ? mochaPhantomJS.run() : mocha.run();
    });
  ```

  It redirects from `/specRunner.html` to `/2,1` and the console error repeats about every 30 seconds.
  [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've found that it's not necessarily an issue with the HTML setup, but rather an issue with a test.

[image]

Setting the `location` variable globally within the file causes the strange redirection (to `/2,1`) and error "Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null".

Moving the variable within the describe statement, on line 4, fixes the problem.

My final HTML is cleaner as well:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Mocha Tests</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/mocha/mocha.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mocha"></div>
  <script src="node_modules/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
  <script>mocha.setup('bdd');</script>
  <script src="node_modules/chai/chai.js"></script>
  <script>var expect = chai.expect;</script>

  <!-- src files -->
  <script src="narcissistic.js"></script>
  <script src="morseCodeDecoder.js"></script>
  <script src="windComponents.js"></script>
  <script src="mineLocation.js"></script>

  <!-- test files -->
  <script src="test/narcissisticTests.js"></script>
  <script src="test/morseTests.js"></script>
  <script src="test/windTests.js"></script>
  <script src="test/mineTests.js"></script>

  <script>mocha.run();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, just tested it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Mocha Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/mocha/mocha.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id='mocha'></div>
  <div id='app'></div>

  <script src="node_modules/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/chai/chai.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script>
    mocha.setup('bdd');
    var expect = chai.expect;
  </script>
  <!-- Tests -->
  <script src="app_test.js"></script>
  <script>
    mocha.run();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Cory, but this isn't working. How did you test it? It's still doing the redirect to `/2,1`